# How do i app a custom web application inside a shopify page

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

i'd like to extend functionality beyond what my shopify theme can do, i want to create an app that would render below the shopify header when user visits a certain link, and will have access to customer id from shopify. is this possible? i want this application to be customer facing, not admin.

Comment: Yep I don't see issues with this kind of an app. Please have in mind that you may need additional liquid logic in order to access the `customer.id` from the front-end.

Comment: is there a way i can combine my react code with liquid?

Comment: No. Liquid is a back-end language it renders before the DOM.